# Libgdx project for iOS displaying libgdx splash when compiling through robovm on simulator?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine, robovm

How can I remove libgdx splash screen which appears on iOS simulator but doesn't showed up in android emulator.

I am compiling my libgdx project through robovm.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to replace the various "Default-" images which are in the RoboVM iOS project's "data" folder.

These are the iOS "launch images" described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

Comment: I can replace that with a black image, but is there a way to disable that splash itself?